# SSRS Report Language

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Whenever I add a report (via *Add New Report* context menu), the Language of the report defaults to `en-US`.  I can then change this value either in Properties or via the underlying XML.  However...

Is it possible to change the value this field defaults to?  I'd prefer it to default to `en-AU`.

Is it possible to have this value be ignored, so the report uses the language setting on the server it's executed on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how languages work in SSRS:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493.aspx

There's a few options. 
You can use `=User!Language` in the ReportLanguage property but this will use the language of the user's browser, not the server.

Another trick is to create a basic report and use it as a template. If you set the language of that template to what you require it will save you having to set it every time. I recommend doing this anyway if you have some standard report features that you always use, like a company logo & the report execution time. It helps create professional consistency betwen reports too.